# How to make Keyboard obscure view in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

It looks like in iOS 14 when the keyboard is shown, it no longer hides the text like it did before.
Although this behaviour is good 95% of the time.

Is there a way I can get it to *not* do that?

I am sure it is a simply modifier/property that I do not know how to do.
Googling is useless, because the results only show me how to make the keyboard not obscure the views. In my case, I want the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out the answer was this

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .all)
```